# How to get the CPLEX MIP gap?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex, opl, ilog

I'm not sure if this is the best SE for my question, or rather the [OR SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/)?

I'm solving an MIP (MLCLSP) with a Fix&Optimize heuristic in IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio and exporting my results to a CSV. This works fine for most of the data, e.g. the solution values of my variables, the objective value, solved time, etc. I only have issues with accessing the **MIP relative gap**.

```
var mipgap = cplex.getMIPRelativeGap();
```

This line results in `CPLEX Error 1217: No solution exists.`, however, no indicator in the Engine Log what would cause that error. Also, when commenting that line out, everything else works fine.
Unfortunately the relevant entry in the [Reference Manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refjsopl/html/IloCplex.html#getMIPRelativeGap) isn't very helpful (for me at least).

Any ideas why this might be and how to fix it?

The Engine log looks like this:

```
CPXPARAM_DetTimeLimit                            15000 Found incumbent of value 53030,000000 after 0,00 sec. (0,09 ticks) Tried aggregator 2 times. MIP Presolve eliminated 740 rows and 180 columns. Aggregator did 8 substitutions. Reduced MIP has 362 rows, 552 columns, and 1733 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 0 binaries, 552 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (1,07 ticks) Tried aggregator 1 time. Reduced MIP has 362 rows, 552 columns, and 1733 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 0 binaries, 552 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (0,82 ticks) MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility. MIP search method: dynamic search. Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 4 threads. Root relaxation solution time = 0,00 sec. (0,93 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/    Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                        53030,0000    43750,0000            17,50%
*     0     0      integral     0    43750,0000    43750,0000       38    0,00% Elapsed time = 0,02 sec. (3,59 ticks, tree = 0,00 MB, solutions
= 2)

Root node processing (before b&c):   Real time             =    0,02 sec. (3,62 ticks) Parallel b&c, 4 threads:   Real time             =   0,00 sec. (0,00 ticks)   Sync time (average)   =    0,00 sec.   Wait time (average)   =    0,00 sec.
                          ------------ Total (root+branch&cut) =    0,02 sec. (3,62 ticks) CPXPARAM_DetTimeLimit                           15000 2 of 2 MIP starts provided solutions. MIP start 'm1' defined initial solution with objective 43750,0000. Tried aggregator 2 times. MIP Presolve eliminated 715 rows and 155 columns. Aggregator did 8 substitutions. Reduced MIP has 387 rows, 577 columns, and 1808 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 552 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (1,28 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,02 ticks) Tried aggregator 1 time. Reduced MIP has 387 rows, 577 columns, and 1808 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 552 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,02 sec. (0,91 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,02 ticks) MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility. MIP search method: dynamic search. Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 4 threads.

Root node processing (before b&c):   Real time             =    0,02 sec. (3,86 ticks) Parallel b&c, 4 threads:   Real time             =   0,00 sec. (0,00 ticks)   Sync time (average)   =    0,00 sec.   Wait time (average)   =    0,00 sec.
                          ------------ Total (root+branch&cut) =    0,02 sec. (3,86 ticks) CPXPARAM_DetTimeLimit                           15000 1 of 3 MIP starts provided solutions. MIP start 'm1' defined initial solution with objective 37500,0000. Tried aggregator 2 times. MIP Presolve eliminated 768 rows and 236 columns. MIP Presolve added 6 rows and 0 columns. Aggregator did 6 substitutions. Reduced MIP has 342 rows, 498 columns, and 1562 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 473 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (1,41 ticks) Probing fixed 0 vars, tightened 3 bounds. Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,21 ticks) Tried aggregator 1 time. MIP Presolve eliminated 1 rows and 1 columns. MIP Presolve modified 4 coefficients. Reduced MIP has 341 rows, 497 columns, and 1559 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 472 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time
= 0,00 sec. (0,85 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,19 ticks) MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility. MIP search method: dynamic search. Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 4 threads. Root relaxation solution time = 0,00 sec. (0,97 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/    Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                        37500,0000    31250,0000            16,67%
*     0+    0                        35000,0000    31250,0000            10,71%
      0     0    31314,2064    15    35000,0000    31314,2064       41   10,53%
      0     0    32074,4750    34    35000,0000      Cuts: 54       62    8,36%
      0     0    32584,6404    20    35000,0000      Cuts: 25       91    6,90%
      0     0    32644,0817    30    35000,0000      Cuts: 29      105    6,73%
      0     0    32782,8515    24    35000,0000      Cuts: 14      115    6,33%
      0     0    32833,6352    17    35000,0000      Cuts: 22      120    6,19%
*     0+    0                        34315,0000    32833,6352             4,32%
      0     0    32833,6352    23    34315,0000      Cuts: 10      125    4,32%
      0     0    32834,1709    20    34315,0000       Cuts: 3      130    4,32%
*     0+    0                        34314,0000    32834,1709             4,31%
*     0+    0                        34201,0000    32834,1709             4,00%
*     0+    0                        34032,0000    32834,1709             3,52%
*     0+    0                        33782,0000    32834,1709             2,81%
      0     2    32834,1709    20    33782,0000    32834,6982      130    2,80% Elapsed time = 0,20 sec. (31,17 ticks, tree = 0,02 MB, solutions
= 7)

Implied bound cuts applied:  29 Flow cuts applied:  17 Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  10 Flow path cuts applied:  11 Zero-half cuts applied:  2 Gomory fractional cuts applied:  10

Root node processing (before b&c):   Real time             =    0,19 sec. (30,99 ticks) Parallel b&c, 4 threads:   Real time             =  0,17 sec. (31,03 ticks)   Sync time (average)   =    0,06 sec.   Wait time (average)   =    0,00 sec.
                          ------------ Total (root+branch&cut) =    0,36 sec. (62,01 ticks) CPXPARAM_DetTimeLimit                          15000 1 of 7 MIP starts provided solutions. MIP start 'm1' defined initial solution with objective 33782,0000. Tried aggregator 2 times. MIP Presolve eliminated 827 rows and 321 columns. MIP Presolve added 4 rows and 0 columns. Aggregator did 9 substitutions. Reduced MIP has 278 rows, 410 columns, and 1282 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 20 binaries, 390 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (1,43 ticks) Probing fixed 0 vars, tightened 2 bounds. Probing time = 0,02 sec. (0,13 ticks) Tried aggregator 1 time. MIP Presolve modified 4 coefficients. Reduced MIP has 278 rows, 410 columns, and 1282 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 20 binaries, 390 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (0,70 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,13 ticks) MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility. MIP search method: dynamic search. Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 4 threads. Root relaxation solution time = 0,00 sec. (0,72 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/    Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                        33782,0000    28782,0000            14,80%
      0     0    28870,7089    20    33782,0000    28870,7089       40   14,54%
      0     0    29921,5804    37    33782,0000      Cuts: 73       63   11,43%
      0     0    30297,2961    16    33782,0000      Cuts: 18       84   10,32%
*     0+    0                        31893,0000    30297,2961             5,00%
      0     0    30338,7836    37    31893,0000      Cuts: 17       95    4,87%
      0     0    30436,2248    30    31893,0000      Cuts: 13      107    4,57%
      0     0    30456,4637    13    31893,0000      Cuts: 11      113    4,50%
      0     0    30477,0706    56    31893,0000      Cuts: 13      120    4,44%
      0     0    30498,5940    36    31893,0000      Cuts: 20      125    4,37%
      0     0    30533,7835    37    31893,0000       Cuts: 6      128    4,26%
*     0+    0                        31662,0000    30533,7835             3,56%
*     0+    0                        31654,0000    30568,6604             3,43%
*     0+    0                        31382,0000    30568,6604             2,59%
      0     2    30533,7835    37    31382,0000    30568,6604      128    2,59% Elapsed time = 0,16 sec. (30,64 ticks, tree = 0,02 MB, solutions
= 5)

Implied bound cuts applied:  21 Flow cuts applied:  13 Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  3 Flow path cuts applied:  20 Zero-half cuts applied:  1 Gomory fractional cuts applied:  11

Root node processing (before b&c):   Real time             =    0,14 sec. (30,48 ticks) Parallel b&c, 4 threads:   Real time             =  0,25 sec. (59,67 ticks)   Sync time (average)   =    0,04 sec.   Wait time (average)   =    0,00 sec.
                          ------------ Total (root+branch&cut) =    0,39 sec. (90,15 ticks) CPXPARAM_DetTimeLimit                          15000 1 of 5 MIP starts provided solutions. MIP start 'm1' defined initial solution with objective 31382,0000. Tried aggregator 2 times. MIP Presolve eliminated 845 rows and 360 columns. Aggregator did 13 substitutions. Reduced MIP has 252 rows, 367 columns, and 1144 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 342 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (1,32 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,14 ticks) Tried aggregator 1 time. Reduced MIP has 252 rows, 367 columns, and 1144 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 342 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (0,63 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,13 ticks) MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility. MIP search method: dynamic search. Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 4 threads. Root relaxation solution time = 0,00 sec. (0,64 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/    Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                        31382,0000    25132,0000            19,92%
      0     0    25244,8113    25    31382,0000    25244,8113       40   19,56%
      0     0    27533,0641    41    31382,0000      Cuts: 84       74   12,26%
*     0+    0                        30999,0000    27533,0641            11,18%
      0     0    27920,4415    20    30999,0000      Cuts: 18       95    9,93%
*     0+    0                        29564,0000    27920,4415             5,56%
      0     0    27953,8964    41    29564,0000      Cuts: 16      106    5,45%
      0     0    28070,3282    42    29564,0000      Cuts: 14      120    5,05%
      0     0    28098,0339    21    29564,0000      Cuts: 13      124    4,96%
      0     0    28114,2658    38    29564,0000       Cuts: 9      130    4,90%
      0     0    28124,0308    52    29564,0000  Flowpaths: 4      137    4,87%
      0     0    28126,2949    38    29564,0000       Cuts: 8      140    4,86%
*     0+    0                        29427,0000    28178,7129             4,24%
*     0+    0                        29343,0000    28178,7129             3,97%
*     0+    0                        29324,0000    28178,7129             3,91%
*     0+    0                        29305,0000    28178,7129             3,84%
      0     2    28126,2949    38    29305,0000    28190,9836      140    3,80% Elapsed time = 0,16 sec. (30,51 ticks, tree = 0,02 MB, solutions
= 7)
*    14    10      integral     0    29272,0000    28190,9836      193    3,69%
*   315    93      integral     0    29212,0000    28421,3841     1104    2,71%
*   453+  121                        29067,0000    28619,5918             1,54%
*   604    56      integral     0    29041,0000    28910,0060     3006    0,45%

Implied bound cuts applied:  24 Flow cuts applied:  10 Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  3 Flow path cuts applied:  19 Zero-half cuts applied:  1 Gomory fractional cuts applied:  15

Root node processing (before b&c):   Real time             =    0,16 sec. (30,40 ticks) Parallel b&c, 4 threads:   Real time             =  0,22 sec. (40,83 ticks)   Sync time (average)   =    0,10 sec.   Wait time (average)   =    0,00 sec.
                          ------------ Total (root+branch&cut) =    0,38 sec. (71,23 ticks) CPXPARAM_DetTimeLimit                          15000 1 of 12 MIP starts provided solutions. MIP start 'm1' defined initial solution with objective 29041,0000. Tried aggregator 2 times. MIP Presolve eliminated 900 rows and 440 columns. Aggregator did 13 substitutions. Reduced MIP has 197 rows, 287 columns, and 884 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 262 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (1,21 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,11 ticks) Tried aggregator 1 time. Reduced MIP has 197 rows, 287 columns, and 884 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 262 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,02 sec. (0,49 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,10 ticks) MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility. MIP search method: dynamic search. Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 4 threads. Root relaxation solution time = 0,00 sec. (0,50 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/    Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                        29041,0000    22791,0000            21,52%
      0     0    22903,2112    25    29041,0000    22903,2112       34   21,13%
      0     0    25185,8934    41    29041,0000      Cuts: 85       68   13,27%
      0     0    25572,1352    35    29041,0000      Cuts: 18       90   11,94%
*     0+    0                        27162,0000    25572,1352             5,85%
      0     0    25617,2128    26    27162,0000      Cuts: 14       98    5,69%
      0     0    25669,8899    14    27162,0000      Cuts: 19      108    5,49%
      0     0    25712,5560    38    27162,0000       Cuts: 9      115    5,34%
      0     0    25743,1148    54    27162,0000       Cuts: 7      125    5,22%
      0     0    25814,7675    52    27162,0000      Cuts: 20      137    4,96%
      0     0    25819,4636    38    27162,0000      Cuts: 21      141    4,94%
      0     0    25819,5024    38    27162,0000       Cuts: 9      143    4,94%
      0     0    25819,8040    39    27162,0000   Flowcuts: 1      144    4,94%
*     0+    0                        27070,0000    25819,8040             4,62%
*     0+    0                        26991,0000    25819,8040             4,34%
*     0+    0                        26960,0000    25819,8040             4,23%
*     0+    0                        26847,0000    25819,8040             3,83%
      0     2    25819,8040    39    26847,0000    25819,8040      144    3,83% Elapsed time = 0,17 sec. (31,64 ticks, tree = 0,02 MB, solutions
= 6)
*   112    27      integral     0    26828,0000    25881,4576      374    3,53%
*   138    37      integral     0    26687,0000    25890,1618      467    2,99%

Implied bound cuts applied:  18 Flow cuts applied:  9 Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  8 Flow path cuts applied:  21 Gomory fractional cuts applied:  14

Root node processing (before b&c):   Real time             =    0,17 sec. (31,54 ticks) Parallel b&c, 4 threads:   Real time             =  0,11 sec. (21,68 ticks)   Sync time (average)   =    0,04 sec.   Wait time (average)   =    0,00 sec.
                          ------------ Total (root+branch&cut) =    0,28 sec. (53,22 ticks) CPXPARAM_DetTimeLimit                          15000 1 of 8 MIP starts provided solutions. MIP start 'm1' defined initial solution with objective 26687,0000. Tried aggregator 2 times. MIP Presolve eliminated 955 rows and 520 columns. Aggregator did 13 substitutions. Reduced MIP has 142 rows, 207 columns, and 624 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 182 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,02 sec. (1,10 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,08 ticks) Tried aggregator 1 time. Reduced MIP has 142 rows, 207 columns, and 624 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 182 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (0,36 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,07 ticks) MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility. MIP search method: dynamic search. Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 4 threads. Root relaxation solution time = 0,00 sec. (0,38 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/    Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                        26687,0000    20437,0000            23,42%
      0     0    20546,7110    25    26687,0000    20546,7110       29   23,01%
      0     0    22823,4321    41    26687,0000      Cuts: 84       63   14,48%
      0     0    23203,9052    20    26687,0000      Cuts: 18       84   13,05%
*     0+    0                        24798,0000    23203,9052             6,43%
      0     0    23233,0297    41    24798,0000      Cuts: 15       92    6,31%
      0     0    23370,5859    47    24798,0000      Cuts: 17      107    5,76%
      0     0    23380,8335    66    24798,0000       Cuts: 7      118    5,71%
      0     0    23396,3490    38    24798,0000      Cuts: 18      134    5,65%
      0     0    23401,6885    48    24798,0000      Cuts: 11      144    5,63%
      0     0    23406,5270    39    24798,0000       Cuts: 9      151    5,61%
*     0+    0                        24543,0000    23406,5270             4,63%
*     0+    0                        24293,0000    23536,4099             3,11%
      0     2    23406,5270    39    24293,0000    23555,5098      151    3,04% Elapsed time = 0,14 sec. (18,87 ticks, tree = 0,02 MB, solutions
= 4)

Implied bound cuts applied:  26 Flow cuts applied:  15 Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  9 Flow path cuts applied:  18 Gomory fractional cuts applied:  14

Root node processing (before b&c):   Real time             =    0,16 sec. (18,79 ticks) Parallel b&c, 4 threads:   Real time             =  0,09 sec. (22,60 ticks)   Sync time (average)   =    0,02 sec.   Wait time (average)   =    0,00 sec.
                          ------------ Total (root+branch&cut) =    0,25 sec. (41,39 ticks) CPXPARAM_DetTimeLimit                          15000 1 of 4 MIP starts provided solutions. MIP start 'm1' defined initial solution with objective 24293,0000. Tried aggregator 2 times. MIP Presolve eliminated 1015 rows and 605 columns. MIP Presolve added 5 rows and 5 columns. Aggregator did 13 substitutions. Reduced MIP has 87 rows, 127 columns, and 364 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 102 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (1,04 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,04 ticks) Tried aggregator 1 time. Reduced MIP has 87 rows, 127 columns, and 364 nonzeros. Reduced MIP has 25 binaries, 102 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators. Presolve time = 0,00 sec. (0,22 ticks) Probing time = 0,00 sec. (0,04 ticks) MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility. MIP search method: dynamic search. Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 4 threads. Root relaxation solution time = 0,00 sec. (0,22 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/    Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

*     0+    0                        24293,0000    18043,0000            25,73%
      0     0    18153,5111    25    24293,0000    18153,5111       25   25,27%
      0     0    20418,7107    41    24293,0000      Cuts: 89       59   15,95%
*     0+    0                        23893,0000    20418,7107            14,54%
      0     0    20865,3751    41    23893,0000      Cuts: 30       82   12,67%
*     0+    0                        23841,0000    20865,3751            12,48%
      0     0    21002,1722    36    23841,0000      Cuts: 17       95   11,91%
      0     0    21051,8993    38    23841,0000      Cuts: 10      102   11,70%
      0     0    21075,6472    36    23841,0000      Cuts: 10      104   11,60%
      0     0    21083,0413    38    23841,0000       Cuts: 7      109   11,57%
*     0+    0                        22452,0000    21083,0413             6,10%
*     0+    0                        21902,0000    21083,0413             3,74%
      0     2    21083,0413    38    21902,0000    21156,8012      109    3,40% Elapsed time = 0,09 sec. (10,49 ticks, tree = 0,02 MB, solutions
= 5)

Implied bound cuts applied:  19 Flow cuts applied:  11 Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  9 Flow path cuts applied:  15 Zero-half cuts applied:  1 Gomory fractional cuts applied:  15

Root node processing (before b&c):   Real time             =    0,08 sec. (10,44 ticks) Parallel b&c, 4 threads:   Real time             =  0,13 sec. (18,70 ticks)   Sync time (average)   =    0,04 sec.   Wait time (average)   =    0,00 sec.
                          ------------ Total (root+branch&cut) =    0,20 sec. (29,14 ticks)
```

Here, the F&O algorithm solves blockwise in 8 iterations and I can extract and display several cplex parameters in the scripting log. Only this MIP gap produces an error...

Comment: Somewhat obviously: the gap cannot be computed before Cplex finds a feasible integer solution.

Comment: Thanks @ErwinKalvelagen, that's given. `cplex.solve();` doesn't fail, `cplex.getObjValue();` works fine too, only the mentioned MIP gap seems to cause an issue for some reason.

Comment: Can you show the log?

Comment: do you use a main block ? if you do and have a Cplex object you should use that Name instead of « cplex «

Comment: Thanks, @AlexFleischer. Yes, I use a main block. I realized that the MIP gap call was outside the loop where I called the solver. Now I moved it up, and it works. However, the output value is a very small float that I don't really understand (even if multiplied by 100). It doesn't reflect at all the last gap shown in the Engine log...

Comment: It may be helpful to retrieve and print the best bound.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen can you please point me to the right command for that? I'm really lost in the documentation...

Comment: getBestObjValue()

Comment: Cheers Mate! I'll try (|cplex.getBestObjValue() - cplex.getObjValue|)/|cplex.getObjVal|, which is the Gurobi MIP gap definition, that should do the job, right? I can't seem to find the ILOG CPLEX definition to compare...

Comment: Yes. The definition used by Cplex is `|bestbound-bestinteger|/(1e-10+|bestinteger|)

`

Comment: Thanks @ErwinKalvelagen, I assume you meant `|bestbound-bestinteger|/(1e-10*|bestinteger|)` with a multiplication in the denominator?

Comment: No. The formula I gave is correct. The term 1e-10 is used to prevent division by zero in case `bestinteger=0`.